# How to get column name based on multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas

### Goal:

Create columns

`fst_imp`: return column name in which value is index of the min value of each row.

`snd_imp`: value is column name  in which value is index of the second small value of each row.

`trd_imp`: value is column name in which value is index of the third small value of each row.

### Example result:

```
   A  B  C  fst_imp  snd_imp trd_imp
0  1  2  3   A         B      C
1  6  5  4   C         B      A
2  7  9  8   A         C      B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one potential solution using [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), the [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor and [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
# Setup
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 1, 1: 6, 2: 7}, 'B': {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 9}, 'C': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 8}})

df.join(pd.DataFrame([df.columns.values[x] for x in np.argsort(df.values)],
                     columns=['fst_imp', 'snd_imp', 'trd_imp']))
```

[out]

```
   A  B  C fst_imp snd_imp trd_imp
0  1  2  3       A       B       C
1  6  5  4       C       B       A
2  7  9  8       A       C       B
```

Or a bit more scalable...

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame([df.columns.values[x] for x in np.argsort(df.values)]))
```

[out]

```
   A  B  C       0       1       2
0  1  2  3       A       B       C
1  6  5  4       C       B       A
2  7  9  8       A       C       B
```

Comment: but if I have more than 3 columns,it will get AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had N columns

Comment: remove the `columns=[...]` arg in that case, should work ok, you may just need a different way of renaming those column headings

Comment: pd.DataFrame([df.columns.values[x][:3] for x in np.argsort(df.values)],
                     columns=['fst_imp', 'snd_imp', 'trd_imp']) it works